# Pathlib can't find a file on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pathlib

Trying to access a CSV file in the following directory with a systemd service: /path/to/cwd/data/x.csv

Currently, hard-coding the path in the python file in my CWD with `path = '/path/to/cwd/data/x.csv'` allows the service to find the file without issues.

However, if I try to use pathlib like so:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path.cwd() / 'data' / 'x.csv'
```

The service gives me an error:
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/x.csv'**

I get the same error when I try to use the OS library to do `path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data/x.csv')`

I have no idea what's going on, when I compare the output of the paths generated by pathlib and os, they're exactly the same as what I type out, but they don't work and the hardcoded path does.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? More importantly, how are you trying to open the csv file? The code that is opening the csv might not be compatible with pathlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to specify the cwd inside the service.

[Service]
   WorkingDirectory=/PathToCwd

Then run it again.

Comment: Does not make sense but it does work :)